# How to send images between two servers with cURL

Tags: php

I have from where users can submit some data information and images and i would like to save images to another server machine with cURL, i tried different ways to do it but no success till now.

How to transfer images from form submit to another server with cURL

Controller -> form_submit.php

```
public function form_submit(){
    $this->sendData($_FILES);
}

public function sendData($image){
    $curl_handle=curl_init();

    $postData['file'] = $image;
    $fields_string = http_build_query($postData);

    $headers = array("Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data");
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://server2.com/api');
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

    $exec = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);
}
```

Server 2

```
    foreach ($this->input->post('file') as $image) {

        $uploads_dir = './assets/images/test/';

        if (!is_dir($uploads_dir)) {
            mkdir($uploads_dir, 0777, true);
        }

        move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$image['name']);
    }
```

im not getting any error and also images are not saved

Comment: Have you looked at [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius  i tried to send it like this:  $postData['file'] = new CURLFile($image['name'], $image['type'], $image['name']); and in server 2 if i did getimagesize($image['name']) that give me error failed to open stream: No such file or directory